# How to open .ext file extension?

Tags: file-format

I have a file with *.ext extensions. How to open that file in ubuntu? I search on [this](http://whatis.techtarget.com/fileformat/EXT-Extension-file-Norton-Commander), they say that it can open with norton commander in windows.

Update:
The file is zipped sqlite database

Comment: What is it? Where did you get the file from?

Comment: There is no well-defined answer to this. File extensions are not very reliable and nonstandard file extensions are completely hit and miss.  Sounds like somebody copy/pasted an example with a generic extension from somewhere without understanding it.

Comment: .ext can also be image files for example rendered by Maya or Blender (or other 3D modelling progs) but I'm not sure which programs can open them .. you might try gimp (Photoshop can but .. yeah ^^)

Comment: It's a file created by Norton for Windows. So, it's off-topic

Comment: @ArpitAgarwal not necessarily . Can you identify the file with `file name_of_file.ext` ? Plese start with one file and use the file name ratheer then foo.ext or *.ext or bar.ext .

Comment: You should post that as the answer as you did all the work. I would up vote it.

Answer (score 0):

finally i found the answer. thanks for @bodhi.zazen for the command. when I run file thefile.ext it is detect as Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract . And I unzip it. then, I found the file name xxx.dat. so i do the same command file xxx.dat. and the result is SQLite 3.x database. And I browse the database by sqlitebrowser on ubuntu. thank you for your help